# Show $\|f-1_{[0,1/2]}\|_{\infty} \geq 1/2$ for any continuous function $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: measure-theory

Show that for any continuous map $f$ on $[0,1]$, the indicator map on [$0$,$1/2$] and $f$ has norm difference at least $1/2$.
I have been trying to prove it using the intermediate value property of R,but to no avail.Also I have seen a similar question being discussed in this website,but it gives a solution almost neglecting the "almost everywhere" condition.So I shall highly appreciate if anyone can provide a complete proof of the above statement.Thanks for any help.

Comment: If $f$ is continuous, then why do you mention that it is essentially bouned ? And what kind of norm difference do you want ?

Comment: Ah!You are right.I am only considering everything in the infinity norm.

Comment: by infinity norm you mean uniform (or $\sup$) norm ?

Comment: the infinity norm of f I am talking about is inf{M>0:|f|<=M a.e}

Comment: since our $f$ is already continuous function, then considering $L_{\infty}$ norm is the same as uniform norm, right ?

Comment: Not exactly,because the indicator function is not continuous and we want the distance between f and the indicator function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can go for a bit of an easier proof. Let $a$ be your indicator function and denote by $b(x) = \frac12$ for all $x$, so that $|a(x)-b(x)| = \frac12$ for all $x$. Consider a continuous function $f$ and suppose that $|a(x)-f(x)|<\frac12$ for all $x$, in particular $f\geq b$ on $[0,\frac12]$ and $f\leq b$ on $(0,\frac12]$, but then by intermediate value theorem $f  = b$ at some $\hat x$, hence $|f(\bar x) - a(\bar x)| = \frac12$: contradiction.

---

It uses intermediate value theorem as I wasn't sure your *to no avail* means you can't use that, or you can but did not know how.

Comment: I meant that I could not use it with success.

Comment: @Ester: nice, then now you can. The only trick is that in such problems you shall find a continuous function which is far away enough from the original one, and apply the IVT to that continuous function, not to the original discontinuous one.\

Comment: Both the proofs also has the same problem as I mentioned in my question as the totally neglected the "a.e formulation".For example in the last proof if you take the '"a.e consideration" then you do not get a contradiction at the last step.

Comment: @Ester: what do you mean by a.e. formulation? I do not see any a.e. formulation in your question - can you be more precise, please?

Comment: Look at the comments I have made above regarding the norm function of f.

Comment: @Ester: well, take a ball of small radius then - wanna do this yourself, or get a more elaborate hint?

Comment: @Ester: sure, are you joining?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f,g: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary functions and $x,y \in [0,1]$. It follows from the (inverse) triangle inequality that

$$\begin{align*} |f(x)-g(x)| &\geq |g(x)-g(y)|- |g(y)-f(x)| \\ &\geq |g(y)-g(x)| - \underbrace{\big| |g(y)-f(y)| - |f(y)-f(x)| \big|}_{\leq |g(y)-f(y)| + |f(y)-f(x)|} \\ &\geq |g(y)-g(x)| - |g(y)-f(y)| - |f(x)-f(y)|. \end{align*}$$

Hence,

$$|g(y)-g(x)| - |f(y)-f(x)| \leq |f(x)-g(x)| + |g(y)-f(x)| \leq 2 \|g-f\|_{\infty}.$$

Now set $g := 1_{[0,1/2]}$ and let $f$ be a continous function. Since $[0,1]$ is compact, $f$ is uniformly continuous, i.e. for any $\varepsilon>0$ we can pick $\delta>0$ such that $$|x-y| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)| \leq \varepsilon.$$ In particular, if choose $y \in (1/2,1]$ and $x \in [0,1/2]$, $|x-y| < \delta$, we get

$$2 \|g-f\|_{\infty} \geq \underbrace{|g(y)-g(x)|}_{1} - \underbrace{|f(y)-f(x)|}_{\leq \varepsilon} \geq 1- \varepsilon.$$

Since $\varepsilon>0$ is arbitrary, we can let $\varepsilon \to 0$ and obtain

$$2 \|g-f\|_{\infty} \geq 1.$$

Comment: Note that the inequality "...<=2||g-f||" does not hold good everywhere

Comment: @Ester Why? It's the supremum norm. Note that the inequality $$|f(x)| \leq \sup_{y \in [0,1]} |f(y)| = \|f\|_{\infty}$$ is trivially satisfied.