# no continuous function equal to an indicator function a.e

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Consider the function $u: [0,2] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by

$u(x)=\begin{cases} 1, \ 0\leq x \leq 1 \\ 0, \ 1 < x \leq 2 \end{cases}$

I want to show that there does not exist a continuous function $v$ s.t $u=v \ \lambda $-$a.e$.  To do this i obviously assume for contradiction that it is true. My idea was to consider the set

$U:=\{x\in [0,2] \mid 0 < v(x) < 1\}$

and show that this is empty. If i can do this i am done. However that is giving me some difficulties.

Comment: If $U \neq \varnothing$, what follows for $\lambda(U)$?

Comment: This question might be of interest: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1045042/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that there is no continuous function f s.t $f=g$ a.e when $g=1_{[0,\infty)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1982767/show-that-there-is-no-continuous-function-f-s-t-f-g-a-e-when-g-1-0-infty)